# Ошибка "Вы попытались получить доступ к адресу ..."

Tags: joomla, php

Помогите исправить ошибку.

Зашёл в админку панели joomla в общие настройки, выбрал пункт сервер и набедакурил там, а теперь всплывает вот такая ошибка.

> `Вы попытались получить доступ к адресу http://laviza.ru/administrator/index.php?option=com_config, который сейчас недоступен. Убедитесь, что веб-адрес (URL) введён правильно, и попытайтесь перезагрузить страницу.`

Я так полагаю, что нужно исправить файл configuration.php или config.

Comment: В настоящий момент хоть какой-нибудь доступ к машине есть?

Comment: не на сайт не в панель доступа нет

Comment: пока я могу только менять файлы на хостинге

Comment: какие настройки меняли?

Comment: на хостинге пока никаких, только в панели joomla по глупости поменял настройки сервера, поставил галочку да на против STTP кажется

Comment: посмотрите в файле configuration.php есть ли что-то похожее на force_ssl = '1'?

Comment: @Рома Прогер, Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз не хотите мне отвечать на наводящий вопрос, придется предполагать. В **configuration.php** посмотрите, есть ли такая строка:

```
var $force_ssl = '1';
```

если есть, то сделайте так:

```
var $force_ssl = '0';
```

Эта штука отключит **HTTPS**, который вы возможно имели в виду говоря о **STTP**

Comment: Странно, почему во многих CMS ещё не сделана проверка на доступность HTTPS, так поставил галку не там, и будешь думать, что - же случилось с сайтом.

Comment: всё исправилось, после того как я обратился к хостеру, сейчас всё нормально